# Importance of disposing EF DbContext before the console app exits in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am writing a simple console application that does only the following:
1. Query the database for some data.
2. Process this data.
3. Update the database.

I wrote the code, which consists only of the Main method, like the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       try
       {
          var dbContext = new MyDatabaseContext();
          var dbRecord = dbContext.MyTable.First(r => r.Status == 1);

          // Do some work

          dbRecord.Status = 2;
          dbContext.SaveChanges();   
       }
       catch(Exception)
       {
         // left empty
       }    
    }
}
```

A colleague of mine told me that I must enclose the code within a "using" statement to close the connection between the application and the database server,  like the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       try
       {
           using(var dbContext = new MyDatabaseContext())
           {
              var dbRecord = dbContext.MyTable.First(r => r.Status == 1);

              // Do some work

              dbRecord.Status = 2;
              dbContext.SaveChanges();      
           } 
       }
       catch(Exception)
       {
         // left empty
       }  
    }
}
```

I know the importance of disposing an "IDisposable" object, before leaving a scope or when the object is no longer needed, to avoid memory leak and to release resources.

But my understanding is, in my case, the program already ends and I don't need to explicitly dispose the DbContext as no connection will exist between the application and the database server after the application ends.

So, I need to answer the following:

1.Is it important, in my case, to dispose the DbContext object before the program exits?
2. Will the connection be still open even after closing the program (Normally, with an exception, or closed by the user)?
3. What will happen if I don't use the "using" statement?

I will be thankful if you provide the answers with official references.

Please note that my concern is memory and resource leaks. Data loss is not my concern for now.

Comment: In your specific case, the `using` will have no measurable effect.  When the application exits, the connection will be closed.  It *is* a good idea to make using a `using` statement a habit though; even in cases like this.

Comment: Please don’t swallow exceptions like that. It will eventually bite you. At least log them or print them out or return non-zero.

Comment: Yes, using `using` on disposable objects is a good idea even if you know "for certain" that the lifetime of the object will coincide with your application. For example, failing to dispose of a `Stream` before exiting means that you can lose buffered data which is never written out. The unmanaged resources (sockets, files) will be released by the operating system no matter what, so you need never be concerned about leaking anything beyond your process, but "cleanly disposing" avoids data loss, errors/warnings triggered by "rude aborts" and other surprises.

Comment: To put it another way: it is not worth memorizing that in this particular case of using `DbContext`, not disposing it will happen to have no negative effect, because it is not worth "optimizing" the cleanup, and it's not worth the possibility of getting it wrong even once in a case where it was not redundant.

Answer (score 1):

To answer to your 3 questions:

- EF tutorial docs say: "...Also, in most common cases, not calling Dispose at all (either implicitly or explicitly) isn't harmful.". I don't trust most common cases. It's a best practice to do it, and I would. By doing it, you are implicitly sure that every resource your context is using is properly released because the maintainers of this framework say so.
- No, no connection opened because the object holding the connection lives in your program's memory. After the OS chooses to kill the process, there is no more pointer to that connection object. If it's still in memory, it's unreachable so it's like it does not exist. I don't know if Windows implements some strange global connection pooling but, if so, it would be OS-specific and I would never rely on that.
- The using statement defines a scope at the end of which an object will be disposed. So, it translates in implicitly calling the dispose method when the end of the using block is reached. It's cosmetic and helps you better define scopes in your code.